# Python-Z3: How can I access the elements of an And

Tags: python, list, z3, z3py, first-order-logic

I can represent conjunction using a list. For instance, let

```py
x_1 = Int('x_1')
the_list = [Not(500 <= x_1), Not(x_1 <= 500), Not(x_1 <= 300)]

phi_1 = And(the_list)
```

(i.e. `phi_1 = And([Not(500 <= x_1), Not(x_1 <= 500), Not(x_1 <= 300)])`)

Then, I can perform `the_list[0]` and get `Not(500 <= x_1)`.

However, imagine I have been given the conjunction without the list:

```py
phi_2 = And(Not(500 <= x_1), Not(x_1 <= 500), Not(x_1 <= 300))
```

How can I access the elements of an `And` as if it was a list?

Comment: Formatting comment: Use single ticks for inline, triple-ticks for body of code that sits by itself. Tagging the latter by the name `python` gives you coloring. (Try editing your question and you'll see the tags as I applied.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decl` and `arg` calls:

```py
from z3 import *

x_1 = Int('x_1')

phi_2 = And(Not(500 <= x_1), Not(x_1 <= 500), Not(x_1 <= 300))

print(phi_2.decl())
for i in range(phi_2.num_args()):
   print(phi_2.arg(i))
```

This prints:

```
And
Not(x_1 >= 500)
Not(x_1 <= 500)
Not(x_1 <= 300)
```

`decl` returns the function that you're applying, and `arg` gets the respective children. Note how z3 internally rearranged your expressions; it tends to put variables on one side and constants on the other in comparisons, without changing the meaning.

Note that the above would fail if you applied it to an expression that wasn't an application. There are also predicates to recognize what sort of a node you're dealing with, but they're more suitable for advanced/internal uses.(`is_app` is the most obvious one, returning true if the expression is an application of a function to arguments.)

### Checking if an application is AND

If you're given an expression and want to find out if it's an application of `And`, use the `is_and` function:

```py
print(is_and(phi_2))
```

prints `True` for the above definition of `phi_2`. See https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a29dab09fc48e1eaa661cc9366194cb29 for documentation. There are recognizers for many of the constructors you might need. And if any is missing, look at the definition of `is_and` itself in the linked documentation to find out the robust way of adding new ones. (i.e., by comparing to the official enumeration of all operations, as given by: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga1fe4399e5468621e2a799a680c6667cd).

### Why comparison with strings is not a good idea

There are several reasons for this, the most obvious ones being maintainability against typos, change of how z3 prints things in the future, etc. But more importantly, comparison against strings can fail in the following way:

```py
from z3 import *

MyBadFunction = Function('And', IntSort(), IntSort())
print(str(MyBadFunction(IntVal(1)).decl()) == 'And')
```

If you run this, you'll see that it happily prints `True`, which is not what you wanted. If you use `is_and` instead, it'll correctly print `False`. So, never trust the name of anything, and always use internal constants that are defined for this very purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! As an extra, if `f = phi_2.decl()` is done and `f` is `And`, then this `f` cannot be compared to anything but a function. To compare, for instance, `f` to `And`, you need to convert `f` to a string with `str(f)`. Then, one can do `if str(f)=='And'`...

Comment: You really shouldn't compare `str(f)` to anything. Relying on how things are converted to strings is very fragile, and is unlikely to be reliable in subsequent versions of the library. I've added code to show how to check if a node is an `and`-node, or some other kind of z3 application.

Comment: I have replaced my string comparison with your recommendation and it works! Also, I would like to counterargue. I understand using string conversion is not the most elegant movement, but why should this be more fragile? I mean, using, for instance `is_and(f)` vs `str(f)`, makes the code more elegant, but what if `is_and` gets deprecated? In that case, `str` would be still useful. Or am I losing some idea? Thanks again!

Comment: @TheoDeep Because comparisons against string can be fooled easily in the presence of uninterpreted functions, amongst other reasons. I edited the answer to provide an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as always!